# qt 5.2.1 mouse cursor on linuxfb

Tags: c++, qt, qtembedded

even I added “evdevmouse” I can still mouser cursor on screen also windows has no toolbox(minimize,restore down-maximize,close) like 4.8 on 5.2.

I also give log of application . what can be cause of that problem?

Thank you.

http://pastebin.com/nk6MUeWY

Comment: You should add the log (or relevant parts of it) to the question, not just provide link to it (links break and often people don't follow them at SO). Be sure to use the code block formatting for the log, too.

Comment: what if log is so so long?